# How do you specify valid non-zero return codes in fabric?

Tags: python, unix, fabric

I have a bash command that spits out non-standard return codes to indicate different types of success and failure.

I would like to run this command as part of a fabric file while white-listing all valid return codes.

```
from fabric.api import local
local('exit 5') # This will cause an abort even though it is expected behaviour
```

My wish is to do something like:

```
from fabric.api import local, settings
with settigns(valid_exit_codes=[0,5]):
    local('exit 5')
```

I'm currently doing something along the lines of:

```
with settings(warn_only=True):
    output = local('exit 5')

    if output.return_code in [0, 5]:
        return output.return_code
    else:
        abort("Non success return-code: %s" % output.return_code)
```

Any assistance in finding a simpler workaround would be great.

Comment: Looks like `puppet agent --test` [returns non-zero codes by design](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/5490) (something I'm trying to run via Fabric), go figure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Fabric 1.6 there is `ok_ret_codes` setting in `env`:

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/env.html#ok-ret-codes

So you can do something like this:

```
    with fabric.api.settings(ok_ret_codes=[0, 2]):
        fabric.api.sudo('puppet agent -t')
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a patch to fabric will be needed to get what you want. This one should get you there: https://github.com/opie4624/fabric/compare/master...return-codes

Answer (score 1):

You can add append `; echo $?` to your command, and just return the exit code as a string literal.

```
assert local('(exit 5); echo $?').split()[-1] in "0 1 2 3 4 5"
```

This has the benefit of not outputting a warning when warn_only is in effect.